# Invalidating deleted pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, invalidation

```
template<typename T>
someclass<T>& operator=(const someclass<T>& other)
{
    typename std::vector<T *>::const_iterator rhs;
    typename std::vector<T *>::iterator lhs;

    //identity test
    //this->data is std::vector<T *>

    for(lhs = this->data.begin(); lhs != this->data.end(); lhs++)
    {
        delete *lhs;
    }

    this->data.clear(); // this is what I forgot

    this->data.reserve(other.data.size());
    for (rhs = other.data.begin(); rhs != other.data.end(); rhs++)
    {
        if (NULL == *rhs)
        {
            this->data.push_back(NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            this->data.push_back(new T(**rhs));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comments, I forgot to clear out the old pointers in the array. When I invoked the assignment operator for the second time, I got glibc error complaining about double free. The only information provided was the deleted address.

This make me thinking about what to do with such class of deleted pointers - when you don't want to delete them again, and when you do, it is certainly an error. You cannot set them to NULL, because another delete would be correct then. You don't want to keep the value as the memory location can be assigned to newly created object.

What would be good for debugging is some value, like INVALID, which you assign to these pointers saying "invoking delete on this pointer is an error", instead of NULL, which say "invoking delete on this pointer does nothing". Is there something like this?

Comment: That won't be very reliable - you could easily get the invalidation code wrong, and miss the bugs you're trying to catch. A dynamic analysis tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) will reliably catch double deletions, and many other memory errors. (And of course, as the answers say, avoiding manual memory management will prevent such errors in the first place)

Comment: Mike Seymour: right, but suppose I put `*lhs = 0` after the delete. Everything would be fine, but I would have a memory leak there that even valgrind doesn't find

Comment: Yes, if you deliberately mask an error, then you'll make it harder to find. Why would you do that?

Comment: This is not deliberately masking. As far as I know it is a common practice to set pointer to NULL after deleted

Comment: @Dadam: Setting pointer to NULL might be a questionable practice. What would it do here? Make the container grow indefinitely. If user code dutifully checks for NULL, the result is that you may have a program that runs fine (for the time being) but in a sense leaks memory (memory never released and usage increases continuously).

Comment: @visitor: This is what the question is about - that I don't want to set it to NULL, I don't want to keep the original value (as it can be reused by another object, which can be deleted accidentaly), so is there any third option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to write code that does not contain any deletes. Use [`shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) where possible. When you have a container that owns polymorphic objects, you can also use [Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: No no no! Don't use `shared_ptr`. There is no reason to want to give shared ownership to the elements of a private data member. Using `shared_ptr` will obfuscate the lifetimes of objects in the code, and will probably have a performance penalty.

Comment: @Mankarse: in C++03, that's more or less your only option if you want the object to be owned by a standard container. (In C++11, `unique_ptr` is preferable for the reasons you give, but that's not an option without move semantics.)

Comment: @Mankarse: I have not arrived in C++11-land yet :)

Comment: @Mike Seymore: There is no reason to restrict yourself to standard containers. [Boost.Move](http://igaztanaga.drivehq.com/libs/move/doc/html/index.html) can be used to create a reasonable `unique_ptr` (in C++03), which can then be used in the containers from the proposed [Boost.Container](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/move/libs/container/doc/html/index.html) library. There is also [Boost.Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), which is probably the best solution.

Comment: But in the absence of those, `shared_ptr` is a reasonable option. At least the code will not be incorrect.

Comment: Will probably use the `shared_ptr` there with lots of `unique()` asserts, as it doesn't need boost. Can your answer be rephrased to something like "use `auto_ptr` where possible and `shared_ptr` where not (containers)" ?

Answer (score 6):

No. A better idea would be to not use raw pointers when you want to have ownership semantics. If you make the type of `data` be `boost::ptr_vector<T>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` then you will not have to manually manage the lifetimes of your pointers, and the problem will go away.

Your container does not properly support polymorphic objects, as the assignment operator that you have presented will slice the objects in the container when they are assigned to another container. An even better solution may be to just have a `std::vector<T>`. This would only be appropriate if you were not counting on some other property of containers of pointers (such as the non-invalidation of pointers to elements, or potentially faster sorting operations).

Comment: You **must** use some sort of smart pointer if the pointed to objects are to be owned by the `std::vector`.  Otherwise, things like an exception from `push_back` will result in memory leaks.

Comment: @James Kanze: I'm pretty sure that it is _possible_ to not use smart pointers and to still write exception safe code. It would just mean a lot of `catch(...)` blocks and redundant cleanup code. But, no, it is not a good idea!

Comment: I cannot use boost there, othrewise I would happily use the unique_ptr and throw away the destructor. To the slicing: it is an internal class which handle non-polymorphic structures

Comment: @Mankarse I suspect that it's theoretically possible.  Possible with a reasonable development time, or with human programmers, who are fallible, I don't know.  I suspect that it would require enough `catch` blocks that you'd fatally miss one:-).